# SharePoint 2010 Center and Fixed Width of all content on page including the ribbon

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010, centering

All,

I am trying to make the width of the sharepoint 2010 web site to be within a fixed width and centered across the screen.  I would like for it to be 800px and centered.  When i do this, it seems like it starts to work until the ribbion bar renters.

Here is my attempt so far:

```
body.v4/* _lcid="1033" _version="14.0.4536"
_LocalBinding */
body,form{
margin:0px;
width:800px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-toolbar{
font-family:verdana;
font-size:8pt;
text-decoration:none;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink")] */ color:#0072BC;
}
a.ms-toolbar:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1",themeShade:"0.8")] */ color:#005e9a;
}
.ms-toolbar-togglebutton-on{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Darker")] */ border:1px solid #2353b2;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent4-Lightest")] */ background-color:#fffacc;
}
table.ms-toolbar{
height:45px;
border:none;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Light2",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:610,width:1,height:42})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -610px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#fff;
}
table.ms-toolbar{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ border:1px solid #f1f1f2;
}
.ms-menutoolbar{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2-Lightest")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #f1f1f2;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#fff;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Light2",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:610,width:1,height:42})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -610px;
height:45px;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td{
padding:0px 0px 0px 4px;
margin:0px;
border:none;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td a{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink")] */ color:#0072bc;
font-size:8pt;
font-family:verdana;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink",themeShade:"0.82")] */ color:#005e9a;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-menubuttoninactivehover,.ms-buttoninactivehover{
margin:3px;
padding:3px 4px 4px 4px;
border:1px solid transparent;
background-color:transparent;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.ms-menubuttonactivehover,.ms-buttonactivehover{
margin:3px;
padding:3px 4px 4px 4px;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Light1-Darkest",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:431,width:1,height:21})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -431px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#fff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lighter")] */ border:solid 1px #cccccc;
cursor:pointer;
}
.ms-buttoninactivehover{
white-space:nowrap;
}
.ms-buttoninactivehover img,.ms-buttonactivehover img{
margin:0px 1px 0px 0px;
}
td.ms-menutoolbarheader{
font-size:10pt;
font-family:verdana;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ color:#204d89;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:16px;
padding-left:7px;
padding-right:7px;
}
.ms-listheaderlabel{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#204d89;
}
.ms-listheaderlabel,.ms-viewselector,.ms-viewselectortext,.ms-viewselectorhover{
font-size:8pt;
font-family:tahoma;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td td.ms-viewselector,.ms-menutoolbar td td.ms-viewselectorhover,.ms-toolbar td td.ms-viewselector,.ms-toolbar td td.ms-viewselectorhover,td.ms-viewselector{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2-Medium")] */ border:1px solid #D3D6DA;
font-weight:bold;
padding:0px;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td td{
border:none;
}
div.ms-viewselector,div.ms-viewselectorhover{
padding:2px 4px 2px 4px;
cursor:pointer;
}
div.ms-viewselector a,div.ms-viewselectorhover a.ms-menu-a span{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
}
.ms-viewselector-arrow{
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-menutoolbar td td.ms-viewselectorhover,.ms-toolbar td td.ms-viewselectorhover{
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent1",method:"Tinting",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:654,width:1,height:18})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -654px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1-Lighter")] */ border-color:#91cdf2;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1",themeTint:"0.35")] */ background-color:#ccebff;
}
.ms-bottompaging{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background:#ebf3ff;
}
.ms-bottompagingline1{
height:3px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
}
.ms-bottompagingline2,.ms-bottompagingline3{
height:1px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
}
.ms-bottompaging .ms-vb{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
}
.ms-bottompagingline2 img,.ms-bottompagingline3 img,.ms-partline img{
display:none;
}
.ms-paging{
padding-left:11px;
padding-right:11px;
padding-bottom:4px;
font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;
font-size:8pt;
font-weight:normal;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Darker")] */ color:#204d89;
}
.ms-bottompaging .ms-paging{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
}
.ms-menutoolbar .ms-splitbuttondropdown{
padding:3px 2px 0px 2px;
}
.ms-menutoolbar .ms-splitbuttontext{
padding:0px 7px 1px 7px;
}
.ms-splitbutton{
margin:0px 2px;
}
.ms-splitbuttonhover{
margin:0px 2px;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent6-Darker",method:"Tinting",includeRectangle:{x:0,y:431,width:1,height:21})] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -431px;
border-collapse:collapse;
height:22px;
background-color:#fff;
}
.ms-splitbuttonhover .ms-splitbuttondropdown{
padding:3px 1px 0px 2px;
}
.ms-splitbuttonhover .ms-splitbuttontext{
padding:0px 6px 0px 6px;
}
.ms-splitbuttonhover .ms-splitbuttondropdown,.ms-splitbuttonhover .ms-splitbuttontext{
border:solid 1px #cccccc;
cursor:pointer;
}
.ms-propertysheet
{
font-size:1em;
}
.ms-propertysheet th.ms-gridT1
{
text-align:left;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
width:190px;
}
.ms-viewselect a:link{
font-size:8pt;
font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3")] */ color:#003399;
}
select{
font-size:8pt;
font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
}
hr{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3")] */ color:#003399;
height:2px;
}
.ms-input{
font-size:8pt;
font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
}
.ms-treeviewouter{
margin-top:5px;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table td{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border-top:1px solid #add1ff;
}
.ms-quicklaunch .ms-treeviewouter table td{
border-top:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-navheader td,.ms-quicklaunch span.ms-navheader{
padding:1px 4px 4px 4px;
}
div.ms-treeviewouter > div > div{
border:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunch span.ms-navheader{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background-color:#d6e8ff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border-top:1px solid #add1ff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ border-left:solid 1px #f2f8ff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #add1ff;
padding:1px 6px 3px 6px;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-navsubmenu2 td{
border:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-selectednavheader td{
width:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lightest")] */ background-color:#fff699;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-selectednavheader{
border:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunch span{
display:block;
}
.ms-quicklaunch div.ms-navsubmenu1 br{
display:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-selectednav{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Darker")] */ border:solid 1px #d2b47a;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent1",method:"Tinting")] */ background-image:url("/_layouts/images/selectednav.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lightest")] */ background-color:#ffe6a0;
margin:2px;
margin-bottom:0;
width:97%;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-selectednav td{
background:transparent url("/_layouts/images/selectednavbullet.gif");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left top;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border:solid 1px #ffffff;
padding:0px 4px 1px 12px;
margin:0px;
}
table.ms-selectednav td a.ms-selectednav{
background:none;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
}
.ms-quicklaunch table.ms-selectednavheader td{
width:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lighter")] */ background-color:#ffe6a0;
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent1",method:"Tinting")] */ background-image:url("/_layouts/images/selectednav.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border-top:solid 1px #ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border-left:solid 1px #ffffff;
padding:1px 6px 3px 6px;
}
.ms-selectednavheader a{
font-weight:bold;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-selectednavheader a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}
table.ms-navitem td,span.ms-navitem{
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/navBullet.gif");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left top;
padding:3px 6px 4px 16px;
font-family:tahoma;
}
.ms-navsubmenu1{
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ background-color:#f2f8ff;
}
.ms-navsubmenu2{
width:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ background-color:#f2f8ff;
margin-bottom:6px;
}
table.ms-navselected{
padding:2px;
}
table.ms-navselected,span.ms-navselected{
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent6",method:"Tinting")] */ background-image:url("/_layouts/images/SELECTEDNAV.GIF");
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lighter")] */ background-color:#ffe6a0;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
table.ms-navselected td{
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/navBullet.gif");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top left;
padding:3px 6px 4px 17px;
}
table.ms-navheader td{
background-image:none;
}
.ms-navheader a{
font-weight:bold;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3")] */ color:#003399;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-navheader a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-navitem a{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#3b4f65 !important;
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
}
.ms-navitem a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1")] */ color:#44aff6 !important;
text-decoration:underline !important;
}
.ms-quicklaunchouter{
border:none;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
.ms-quicklaunchouter{
margin:0px 1px 2px 1px;
}
.ms-treeviewouter a.ms-navitem{
padding:4px 4px 5px;
margin-left:4px;
border-color:transparent;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid !important;
}
.ms-tvselected a.ms-navitem{
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/selbg.png") repeat-x left top;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1",themeTint:"0.15")] */ background-color:#ccebff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1-Lighter")] */ border-color:#91cdf2;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent1-Lightest")] */ border-top-color:#c6e5f8;
border-width:1px;
border-style:solid !important;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#003759 !important;
display:inline-block;
}
.ms-tvselected a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#003759 !important;
}
table.ms-recyclebin td{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ background-color:#f2f8ff;
width:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border-top:solid 1px #ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border-left:solid 1px #ffffff;
padding:3px 5px 7px 3px;
}
table.ms-recyclebin td a{
font-weight:bold;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Darker")] */ color:#008800;
text-decoration:none;
}
table.ms-recyclebin td a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-quickLaunch{
padding-top:5px;
}
.ms-quickLaunch h3{
font-size:1em;
font-weight:normal;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2")] */ color:#929fad;
margin:0px 0px 6px 10px;
}
.ms-quicklaunchheader{
padding:2px 6px 4px 10px;
font-weight:bold;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lighter")] */ color:#676767;
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/quickLaunchHeader.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background-color:#d6e8ff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ border-left:solid 1px #f2f8ff;
 margin-left:-7px;
font-size:inherit;
}
.ms-quicklaunchheader a,.ms-unselectednav a{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Lighter")] */ color:#676767 !important;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-quicklaunchheader a:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000 !important;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-navline{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Darker")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #adadad;
}
.ms-navwatermark{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lighter")] */ color:#ffdf88;
}
.ms-selectednav{
border:1px solid #2353b2;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lightest")] */ background:#fff699;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:2px;
}
.ms-unselectednav{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ border:1px solid #83b0ec;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:2px;
}
.ms-verticaldots{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ border-right:1px solid #83b0ec;
border-left:none;
}
.ms-nav{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ background-color:#83b0ec;
font-family:tahoma;
}
.ms-globalTitleArea{
text-align:right;
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/siteTitleBKGD.gif");
background-position:right top;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:0px;
padding-top:1px;
}
.ms-titlearea{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Lighter")] */ color:#666666;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
letter-spacing:.1em;
}
.ms-titlearea a
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Darker")] */ color:#3966bf;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-titlearea a:hover
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-titlearealeft
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background-color:#d6e8ff;
}
TD.ms-titleareaframe,Div.ms-titleareaframe,.ms-pagetitleareaframe{
background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -461px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background-color:#d6e8ff;
text-align:left;
}
div.ms-titleareaframe{
height:100%;
}
.ms-pagetitleareaframe table{
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/topshape.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:332px 4px;
height:54px;
}
.ms-titlearealine{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ background-color:#83b0ec;
}
.ms-titleareaframe table td.ms-titlearea,.ms-areaseparator table td.ms-titlearea,.ms-pagetitleareaframe table td.ms-titlearea{
padding:7px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.ms-sitemapdirectional,.ms-sitemapdirectional a{
unicode-bidi:embed;
}
.ms-areaseparatorcorner{
background-image:url("/_layouts/images/framecornergrad.gif");
background-position:left top;
background-repeat:repeat-y;
height:8px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Medium")] */ border-right:1px solid #6f9dd9;
}
td.ms-areaseparatorleft{
background:#d6e8ff url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -461px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Medium")] */ border-right:1px solid #6f9dd9;
height:100%;
}
div.ms-areaseparatorleft{
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:-143px 0px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Medium")] */ border-right:1px solid #6f9dd9;
height:100%;
}
div.ms-areaseparatorright{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Medium")] */ border-left:1px solid #6f9dd9;
padding-right:2px;
height:100%;
}
.ms-titlearearight .ms-areaseparatorright{
background:#d6e8ff url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x -0px -461px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent5-Medium")] */ border-left:1px solid #6f9dd9;
padding-right:2px;
height:100%;
}
.ms-areaseparator{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent4-Lightest")] */ background-color:#ffeaad;
border-right:none;
border-left:none;
padding-left:5px;
height:61px;
}
.ms-pagemargin{
background-color:#83b0ec;
height:100%;
}
td.ms-rightareacell div.ms-pagemargin{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ background-color:#83b0ec;
height:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ border-left:solid 1px #83b0ec;
}
.ms-bodyareacell{
vertical-align:top;
}
.ms-pagebottommargin,.ms-pagebottommarginleft,.ms-pagebottommarginright{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ background:#83b0ec;
}
.ms-bodyareapagemargin{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ background:#83b0ec;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border-top:1px solid #6f9dd9;
}
.ms-bodyareaframe{
vertical-align:top;
height:100%;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border:1px solid #6f9dd9;
}
.ms-bodyareaframe{
padding:10px;
}
.ms-pagetitle{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
font-family:verdana;
font-size:16pt;
margin:0px 0px 4px 0px;
font-weight:normal;
}
.ms-pagetitle a{
text-decoration:none;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
margin:0;
font-weight:normal;
}
.ms-pagetitle a:hover{
}
.ms-vh table.ms-selectedtitle,.ms-vh2 table.ms-selectedtitle,.ms-vh-icon table.ms-selectedtitle,.ms-vh table.ms-unselectedtitle,.ms-vh2 table.ms-unselectedtitle,.ms-vh-icon table.ms-unselectedtitle{
height:21px;
}
.ms-vh table.ms-selectedtitle,.ms-vh2 table.ms-selectedtitle,.ms-vh-icon table.ms-selectedtitle{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lighter")] */ background-color:#dde1e5;
border:none;
}
.ms-vh2 .ms-selectedtitle .ms-vb,.ms-vh2 .ms-unselectedtitle .ms-vb{
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:1px;
}
.ms-vh-icon .ms-selectedtitle .ms-vb,.ms-vh-icon .ms-unselectedtitle .ms-vb{
padding-left:0px;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-propertysheet th.ms-vh2,.ms-propertysheet th.ms-vh2-nofilter{
font-family:tahoma;
}
.ms-listviewtable .ms-vh2,.ms-summarystandardbody .ms-vh2{
padding:1px 1px 0px 1px;
}
.ms-listviewtable .ms-vb2,.ms-summarystandardbody .ms-vb2{
padding-left:2px;
padding-right:7px;
}
.ms-selectedtitle{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent4-Darker")] */ border:1px solid #b09460;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.ms-selectedtitlealternative
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent4-Darker")] */ border:1px solid #b09460;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.ms-unselectedtitle{
background-color:transparent;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
.ms-newgif{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:5px;
}
.ms-menuimagecell{
/* [RecolorImage(themeColor:"Accent1",method:"Tinting")] */ background:url("/_layouts/images/selectednav.gif") repeat-x;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent6-Lighter")] */ background-color:#ffe6a0;
cursor:pointer;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ border:solid 1px #ffffff;
padding:0px;
height:18px;
}
.ms-vh .ms-menuimagecell,.ms-vh2 .ms-menuimagecell,.ms-vh-icon .ms-menuimagecell{
height:20px;
}
.ms-vh .ms-menuimagecell img,.ms-vh2 .ms-menuimagecell img,.ms-vh-icon .ms-menuimagecell img{
margin-top:2px;
margin-bottom:2px;
}
.ms-descriptiontext{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
text-align:left;
}
.ms-statusdescriptiontext
{
color:#4c4c4c;
background-color:#FFFF00;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
text-align:left;
}
.ms-webpartpagedescription{
font-family:verdana;
font-size:8pt;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Lighter")] */ color:#5a5a5a;
padding:8px 12px 0px 12px;
}
.ms-separator
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2",themeShade:"0.02")] */ color:#f1f1f2;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
border:none;
padding-left:4px;
font-size:10pt;
}
.ms-rtetoolbarmenu .ms-separator{
padding-left:0px !important;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Medium")] */ color:#83b0ec;
}
.ms-separator img
{
height:12px;
width:1px;
margin:0px 1px 0px 1px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light2",themeShade:"0.02")] */ background:#f1f1f2;
}
.ms-propertysheet th.ms-authoringcontrols
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ background-color:#f1f1f2;
text-align:left;
}
table.ms-authoringcontrols > tbody > tr > td{
vertical-align:middle;
}
td.ms-authoringcontrols > label,td.ms-authoringcontrols > span > label,td.ms-authoringcontrols > table > tbody > tr > td > label{
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-propertysheet th.ms-linksectionheader
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:8pt;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
}
.ms-linksectionitemdescription{
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:7px;
}
.ms-propertysheet .ms-sectionheader a,.ms-propertysheet .ms-sectionheader a:hover
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Lighter")] */ color:#525252;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-partline
{
height:3px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark2",themeTint:"0.17")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #EBEBEB;
}
.ms-propertysheet{
font-family:verdana;
font-size:1em;
text-align:left;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
}
.ms-propertysheet th{
font-family:verdana;
font-size:8pt;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
font-weight:normal;
}
.ms-propertysheet a{
text-decoration:none;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Darker")] */ color:#3966bf;
}
.ms-propertysheet a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
}
.ms-vh,.ms-vh2,.ms-vh-icon-empty,.ms-vhImage,.ms-vh2-nograd,.ms-vh3-nograd,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon,.ms-ph{
font-weight:normal;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Medium")] */ color:#b2b2b2;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:top;
}
.ms-vh-icon{
vertical-align:middle;
}
.ms-gb,.ms-gb2,.ms-gbload,.ms-vb-tall,.ms-vb-user,.ms-pb,.ms-pb-selected td{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
}
.ms-gb a,.ms-gb2 a{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3")] */ color:#003399;
}
.ms-vh,.ms-vh2,.ms-vh-icon,.ms-vh-icon-empty,.ms-vhImage,.ms-gb,.ms-gb2,.ms-gbload,.ms-vb,.ms-vb2,.ms-vb-tall,.ms-vb-user,.ms-vh2-nograd,.ms-vh3-nograd,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon,.ms-pb,.ms-pb-selected,.ms-ph{
font-size:8pt;
line-height:1.2;
font-family:Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.ms-vh,.ms-vh2,.ms-vh2-nograd,.ms-vh3-nograd,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon,.ms-ph{
white-space:nowrap;
}
.ms-vh,.ms-vh2,.ms-vh-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon,.ms-viewheadertr .ms-vh-group,.ms-vh2-nograd,.ms-vh3-nograd,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-ph,.ms-pickerresultheadertr{
background-repeat:repeat-x;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:0px;
}
.ms-viewheadertr th{
padding-top:5px !important;
}
.ms-disc .ms-viewheadertr th.ms-vh2{
padding:1px 5px 0px 4px;
}
.ms-disc .ms-vh2 .ms-selectedtitle .ms-vb,.ms-disc .ms-vh2 .ms-unselectedtitle .ms-vb{
padding-left:4px;
}
th.ms-vh3-nograd{
width:12px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Darker")] */ color:#949494;
font-size:8pt;
font-family:tahoma,sans-serif;
}
.ms-vh .ms-vh{
background-image:none;
border-left:none;
padding-left:1px;
background-color:transparent;
}
.ms-vh2,.ms-ph{
padding:3px 8px 1px;
}
.ms-vh-div{
padding-top:5px;
}
.ms-vh-icon,.ms-vh2-nograd-icon,.ms-vh2-nofilter-icon{
width:12px;
}
.ms-vh-icon{
padding-left:6px;
padding-right:4px;
padding-bottom:3px;
}
.ms-vh-icon-empty{
width:0px;
}
.ms-vh a,.ms-vh a:visited,.ms-vh2 a{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Lightest")] */ color:#7f7f7f;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-vh a:hover,.ms-vh2 a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-imnImgTD
{
padding-right:2px;
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.ms-vhltr .ms-imnImgTD
{
padding-right:2px;
}
.ms-vhrtl .ms-imnImgTD
{
padding-left:2px;
}
.ms-imnTxtTD
{
padding-top:0px;
}
.ms-vhImage{
width:18pt
}
.ms-standardheader{
font-size:1em;
margin:0em;
text-align:left;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#525252;
}
.ms-formlabel h3.ms-standardheader{
font-weight:normal;
color:auto;
}
.ms-linksectionheader .ms-standardheader{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#000000;
}
.ms-gb{
height:22px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
font-weight:bold;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lighter")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #8ebbf5;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ border-top:1px solid #f9f9f9;
padding-bottom:3px;
}
.ms-gb .ms-vb2{
font-weight:normal;
}
.ms-listviewtable .ms-gb,.ms-listviewtable .ms-gb2{
padding-top:14px;
}
.ms-gb2{
height:22px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
padding-bottom:3px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Accent3-Lightest")] */ border-bottom:1px solid #e3efff;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1-Lightest")] */ border-top:1px solid #f9f9f9;
}
.ms-gbload{
height:22px;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1-Medium")] */ color:#4c4c4c;
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Light1")] */ background-color:#ffffff;
padding-bottom:3px;
}
.ms-vb,.ms-vb2,.ms-vb-user,.ms-vb-tall,.ms-pb,.ms-pb-selected
{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Dark1")] */ color:#6d6f72;
vertical-align:top;
}
.ms-vb a:link,.ms-vb2 a:link,.ms-vb-user a:link{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink")] */ color:#0072BC;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-vb a:hover,.ms-vb2 a:hover,.ms-vb-user a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-vb a:visited,.ms-vb2 a:visited,.ms-vb-user a:visited{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink")] */ color:#0072BC;
text-decoration:none;
}
.ms-vb a:visited:hover,.ms-vb2 a:visited:hover,.ms-vb-user a:visited:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor:"Hyperlink")] */ color:#0072BC;
text-decoration:underline;
}
.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb a:link,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb2 a:link,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb-user a:link,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb a:visited,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb2 a:visited,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb-user a:visited,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb a:visited:hover,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb2 a:visited:hover,.ms-alternatingstrong .ms-vb-user a:visited:hover{
/* [ReplaceColor(themeColor
```

Comment: What html are you using that css with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

In the v4 masterpage, you should use

```
<div scroll="no" id="s4-workspace" class="s4-nosetwidth" style="overflow:visible; width:1024px; margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto; background:white;">
```

after the body tag

Answer (score 0):

Add table in your masterpage before div tag starts...

```
<table align="center" width="1003px" > <tr> <td> 
</td> 

<div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
.
.
.
</div> 

</td> </tr> </table> 
</form>
```

and make few changes in your style sheet too

```
body #s4-ribbonrow{
width:1003px !important;

}
```